# Proof that there are infinitely many irrational numbers!

Tags: irrational-numbers

I want to prove that there are infinitely many irrational numbers! How can I do that?

I don't know where or how to start so any hint is appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: $n\sqrt2$ is irrational for every non-zero integer $n$.

Comment: $\sqrt{p}$ for any prime $p$ is irrational. We know how many primes there are.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Show that there is an injection from an infinite set, e.g. $\Bbb N$, into the set of irrational numbers. That is, send every natural number $n$ to some irrational number. Also, recall that if we take a non-zero rational number, its sum and product with any irrational number is irrational.

Answer (score 3):

Several ideas :

*Based on the fact that the set of natural numbers is infinite:*

Take your favourite irrational number, say $\;\pi\;$, and now look at  the set $\;\{n\pi\;;\;n\in\Bbb N\}\;$ . Prove this set is infinite and all its elements are irrational

*Based on the fact that* $\;|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0=|\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb N|\;$ : By difference of cardinalities , if $\;Irr=$  the set of irrational numbers, then

$$|Irr|=|\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q|=2^{\aleph_0}-\aleph_0=2^{\aleph_0}\;\;\text{(yes, that difference is ugly...)}$$

Comment: This is why pedro says he prefers words over notation.

Comment: @ Nick ...?....

Answer (score 1):

The radical of **any** order $\geqslant2$ out of **any** prime is irrational, for the same reasons that $\sqrt2$ also is. And since [the number of primes is infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)... $($Unless what you wanted to prove is that the number of irrationals is *uncountable*, in which case this approach is *not* enough...$)$